# Owl Carousel 2 Navigation In Slide

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I am using the **Owl Carousel 2** jquery plugin, and am trying to have the navigation buttons contained within the slides. My html is very simple:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">    
<div>
  <p>Slide 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quisquam rem assumenda, ullam, beatae earum animi magnam! Reiciendis, laboriosam, itaque.</p>

  <div class="customNavigation">
    <a class="prev">Previous</a>
    <a class="next">Next</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div>
  <p>Slide 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quisquam rem assumenda, ullam, beatae earum animi magnam! Reiciendis, laboriosam, itaque.</p>

  <div class="customNavigation">
    <a class="prev">Previous</a>
    <a class="next">Next</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div>
  <p>Slide 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat quisquam rem assumenda, ullam, beatae earum animi magnam! Reiciendis, laboriosam, itaque.</p>

  <div class="customNavigation">
    <a class="prev">Previous</a>
    <a class="next">Next</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

And then I am calling the plugin like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        items: 1,
    })      
});
```

Now I just need to get the links to work with the plugin! Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: so u want the next and prev to work right..??

Comment: Yep I want them to make the carousel function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hope this might help you mate.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
});
owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
$(".prev").click(function () {
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});

$(".next").click(function () {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w5b38r6v/)